# Need help when proxying my device to another location through my phone and I need to capture a Charles log?

Tags: charles-proxy

Title: Need help when proxying my device to another location through my phone and I need to capture a Charles log

Environment: Android or iOS

Steps to reproduce: Example below:

- Put in an IP address of another location in the settings of the phone, check Yahoo to see if your in another location (Canada)
- Need to capture a Charles log file but can't use an IP address in the phone to connect to my laptop because it's using another proxy on the phone.

Expected Result: Need a way to proxy to Canada and capture a Charles log file using reproducible steps above.

Actual Result: Can't find a way!

Answer (score 0):

Connect your mobile to use Charles as a proxy, and open VPN on your computer choose Canada as your location.
When you browse from your mobile you will see that you are in Canada.

Comment: Yes, but I don't see metrics.  I need to see metrics, I've done this setup before but unless you have the actual test I'm all ears.